# screen keeps dimming

Tags: power-management, screen

Since last week, my screen in ubuntu 16.04 keeps dimming even while I am active. I unchecked the dim screen to save power tickmark in the lock and screen settings, and I am running on AC power too. Nevertheless the screen dims every minute or so (I set the limit to 30 minutes but it should never
dim). It dims even while I am typing or scrolling with the mouse.

Anyone having an idea why the settings do not work suddenly?

Answer (score 0):

Having similar trouble. Screen blanks out if the mouse or keyboard are idle for less than 10 seconds!

Anyone see behavior like this?