# Ubuntu 19.10 keeps locking screen despite screen locking / dimming etc etc

Tags: 19.10, lock-screen

I have disabled all screen locking / dimming / power saving. Nevertheless Ubuntu 19.10 / Gnome keeps randomly locking screen. (Started about 3 weeks ago when I temporarily changed settings to faster locking, but despite having changed the settings back, the locking still happens.)

The only pattern I can detect is that the lock happens when I've left the screen idle and then get back to the screen. I.e., the lock happens as soon as I touch the mouse (not before). However, that's not the only time, and it's not consistent either.

Any ideas? Might be similar to this: [screen keeps dimming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860577/screen-keeps-dimming) (2016/2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a fix via the Ubuntu / gnome-settings, but it did occur to me that I could uninstall the screensaver itself:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-screensaver
```

While that has completely disabled the screen saver, it's also definitely stopped the accidental locks. (Locking by closing laptop lid and via keyboard shortcut etc still works.)